# How do I animate all elements after removed element in a ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-animations

Given the following ngFor, which is loop in a loop:

TS:

```
myGroupedArray: { groupName:string, nestedArray: { elementName: string }[] }[]
```

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let gp in myGroupedArray | async">

    <div>{{gp.groupName}}</div>

    <div *ngFor="let el in gp.nestedArray">
        {{el.elementName}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Lets say I want to remove item N from the nested array. How do I apply an animation to all the elements *after* the removed element N.

(The objective is to stagger the trailing elements upwards.)